# Spring jdbcTemplate data access and java algorithms

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have one method which must return data in DAO.

Department model:

```
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String departmentName;
    private List<Employees> employeesInThisDepartment;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

Employees model:

```
public class Employees implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String department;
    private String fullName;
    private Date birthday;
    private int salary;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

And method in DAO:

```
@Override
public Department findByDepartmentNameWithEmployees(String departmentName) {
    String sql = "select d.id, d.departmentName, e.id, e.fullName, e.department, e.birthday" +
            ", e.salary from department as d left join employees as e on d.departmentName = e.department " +
            "where lower(d.departmentName) = lower(:departmentName)";
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("departmentName", departmentName);
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, map, (rs, rowNum) -> {
        Department department = new Department();
        department.setId(rs.getLong("department.id"));
        department.setDepartmentName(rs.getString("department.departmentName"));
        department.setEmployeesInThisDepartment(new ArrayList<>());

        while (rs.next()){
            Employees employees = new Employees();
            employees.setId(rs.getLong("employees.id"));
            employees.setFullName(rs.getString("employees.fullName"));
            employees.setDepartment(rs.getString("employees.department"));
            employees.setBirthday(rs.getDate("employees.birthday"));
            employees.setSalary(rs.getInt("employees.salary"));
            department.getEmployeesInThisDepartment().add(employees);
        }
        return department;
    });
}
```

This method must return one department with list of all employees who works in this department, but it misses the first employee in the list.
Why is this happening? (SQL part is working correctly, I think that the problem is with the loop?)

Comment: Don't call `rs.next()`... The `mapRow` method (which is used) is called for each row in the resultset. You are basically working against instead of with the framework. Every row in the resultset will contain all the department information and information of 1 employee, you are now always skipping the first one. You should use a `ResultSetExtractor` instead of a `RowMapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, problem in the loop. According to [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html):

> Implementations must implement this method to map each row of data in
>   the ResultSet.

So you do not need to invoke `rs.next()`, just remove this loop wrapper and move block

```
    Department department = new Department();

    department.setEmployeesInThisDepartment(new ArrayList<>());
```

outside `return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, map, (rs, rowNum) -> { ... }`. I.e.:

```
Department department = new Department();
department.setEmployeesInThisDepartment(new ArrayList<>());

jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, map, (rs, rowNum) -> {
        department.setId(rs.getLong("department.id"));
        department.setDepartmentName(rs.getString("department.departmentName"));

        Employees employees = new Employees();
        employees.setId(rs.getLong("employees.id"));
        employees.setFullName(rs.getString("employees.fullName"));
        employees.setDepartment(rs.getString("employees.department"));
        employees.setBirthday(rs.getDate("employees.birthday"));
        employees.setSalary(rs.getInt("employees.salary"));
        department.getEmployeesInThisDepartment().add(employees);
});
return department;
```

Comment: missing a `final` on `department` IMHO

Comment: Could be not needed in Java 8 as it actually final. But I've written this code from mind without compiler, so I will leave this detail for SO

Comment: Ok, i can`t set id for department without rs. Rs does not exist outside lambda

Comment: When I just remove loop I get exeption "Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 3"

Comment: then move this particular line of code inside lambda

Comment: This too don`t working. "Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 3"

Comment: ??? I've provided you an idea how to solve core problem. Stackoverflow is not that place that somebody will do your job for you and "faster".